# CakePHP 3 and VueJS - use v-model to set default Form's selectbox

Tags: php, cakephp, vue.js

I'm using CakePHP `Form` helper to create form input fields. When a user edit an item, it will pre-fill the fields with data. I use v-model on each input field to make sure data is correctly populated.

It's all good for the textboxes as data is bound correctly. But for `<select>` fields, v-model doesn't seem to work. I've tried using default property for the Form->input() but no help. Here's some code:

```
<div class="fields">
    <?= $this->Form->input('email', [
        'label' => __('Email'),
        'type' => 'email',
        'v-model' => 'emailModel',
        'placeholder' => __('Required'),
        '@keydown.enter.stop.prevent' => 'return false;',
        '@keyup.enter.stop.prevent' => 'onSubmit()'
    ]); ?>
    <?= $this->Form->input('status', [
        'label' => __('Status'),
        'type' => 'select',
        'default' => '{{userStatus}}',
        'options' => [
            1 => 'Active',
            2 => 'Inactive'
        ],
        '@keydown.enter.stop.prevent' => 'return false;',
        '@keyup.enter.stop.prevent' => 'onSubmit()'
    ]); ?>
</div>
```

The `email` textbox has correct data filled, but not for the `status` selectbox. But if I replace `{{userStatus}}` with, for example, `2`, it will set the default option to `Inactive`, even though `{{userStatus}}` itself has value `2`.

How do I go about solving this?

Answer (score 1):

I am new to VueJS but I came across the same question. The VueJS documentation states:

> v-model will ignore the initial value, checked or selected attributes found on any form elements. It will always treat the Vue instance data as the source of truth. **You should declare the initial value on the JavaScript side**, inside the data option of your component.
> https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Basic-Usage

Therefore, you need to assign your data.userStatus with your default value.

```
var vm = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        statusModel: 2 // The default value goes here
    }
});
```

PHP Side:

```
<div class="fields">
    <?= $this->Form->input('email', [
        'label' => __('Email'),
        'type' => 'email',
        'v-model' => 'emailModel',
        'placeholder' => __('Required'),
        '@keydown.enter.stop.prevent' => 'return false;',
        '@keyup.enter.stop.prevent' => 'onSubmit()'
    ]); ?>
    <?= $this->Form->input('status', [
        'label' => __('Status'),
        'type' => 'select',
        'v-model' => 'statusModel',
        'options' => [
            1 => 'Active',
            2 => 'Inactive'
        ],
        '@keydown.enter.stop.prevent' => 'return false;',
        '@keyup.enter.stop.prevent' => 'onSubmit()'
    ]); ?>
</div>
```

Hope this helps.